# Insertion Of Data From Database Into ListView Control WindowForms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

> I am trying to select data from the database to listview, but it is not working .There are no errors or anything but the code is totally unresponsive.....

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.GridLines = true;
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ListView_Data;Integrated Security=True";
        cmd.CommandText = @"select ProductName,Price,Quantity from producttable";
        con.Open();

        cmd.Connection = con;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        string[]ar=new string[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ar[i] = dt.Rows[0][i].ToString();
        }
        ListViewItem itm = new ListViewItem(ar);

        listView1.Items.Add(itm);

    }
```

Comment: It must be something about this line...
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ListView_Data;Integrated Security=True";

Comment: Does your DataTable have data?

Comment: place the break point here `ar[i] = dt.Rows[0][i].ToString();` and check what happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
string[]ar=new string[dt.Columns.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int c=0;c <dt.Columns.Count; c++)
        ar[c] = dt.Rows[i][c].ToString();

    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(ar));
}
```

But, I would like to preffer to use this.

```
ListViewItem li = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    li = listView1.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
    for (int c = 1; c < dt.Columns.Count; c++)
        li.SubItems.Add(dt.Rows[i][c].ToString());
}
```

Comment: If you want reload the data, don't forget listView1.Items.Clear(); otherwise you have duplicated items.

Comment: Here is a good overview about DataBindings on ListView: [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10008/Data-binding-a-ListView)

Comment: My comment is meaning in general and not explicit to this example. Maybe other users read this thread and run in this issue. And when you go so deep in details, don't forget the error handling. ;) I'm not criticize your answer, absolutly not. @Nimesh

Comment: Thanks everyone, the above mentioned code helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

You loop over all the rows and create an unique array that you try to use as a constructor for a single ListViewItem.

You could simplify your code with

```
foreach(DataRow d in dt.Rows)
    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(d.ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()));
```

but this seems to be a classical case where you loop two times.

- The first time, the call to `DataAdapter.Fill` loops over your results
  to fill a DataTable
- The second time, you loop over the DataTable rows to fill the
  ListView.

With a small dataset there is no big concern, but if you return a large amount of data and you don't need to keep the DataTable for other purposes, then I suggest to use a SqlDataReader and prepare directly a ListViewItem without first filling a DataTable.